# (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) does not have write access to 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: security, iis, iis-6

I've read all post regarding this issue, and did almost all possible solution stated in there but with no luck.

I even created new account, granted the account to have access to net folders
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files, using 
aspnet_regiis -da computername\newuseraccount,
use that account as identity in DefaultAppPool in IIS.
It just changes the (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) name to the newly created account computername\newuseraccount in the error message.

What could be the problem here?
I also manually added the new account to the ...\Temporary ASP.NET Files folder,
but no effect.

Any idea which could resolve this issue or that could explain why such scenario is happening will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at effective permissions for that folder. Monitor not only 'allow' permissions, but also 'deny'. It might be the case that another group (or even global Everyone) is denied write access explicitly and this overrides the 'allow' permissions...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the content of the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` directory?

The content will be automatically regenerated after cleaning.

How to clean the directory is presented here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2008/08/11/clearing-out-temporary-asp-net-files.aspx